# Exercise 1.2 in Peter Norvig's Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In exercise 1.2 of Peter Norvig's Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming the reader is asked to

> Write a function to exponentiate, or raise a number to an integer
>   power. For example: (power 3 2) = 3^2 = 9.

The provided solution is this:

```
  (defun power (x n)
    (cond ((= n 0) 1)
          ((evenp n) (expt (power x (/ n 2)) 2))
          (t (* x (power x (- n 1))))))
```

Of course this is correct. Now I feel a bit stupid, but isn't he using the built-in version of the very function he implements? Why would I implement `power` using `expt`?
Or what is the difference between `expt` and `power`?

Comment: Are you sure he didn't use `power` instead of `expt`? Is there an errata web site?

Comment: I found an errata site http://norvig.com/paip-errata.html but this isn't in it.

Comment: You're right, it's  written this way in http://norvig.com/paip/intro.lisp

Comment: Thanks for the links, I also checked the errata and looked for an online version, but couldn't find it.

Comment: I mean, why not just write (defun power-wtf (x n)
  (expt x n))?

Comment: If he would use `power` instead of `expt` it actually would end up in an endless loop because (power x 2) would end up calling (power x 2).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like he's only using this for the simplest case of squaring a number, rather than for all the general cases. It may be because this is very early in the book, before he's taught how to bind local variables, so he didn't want to write:

```
(defun power (x n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 1)
        ((evenp n)
         (let ((temp (power x (/ n 2)))
           (* temp temp)))
        (t (* x (power x (- n 1))))))
```

It can't use `(power (power x (/ n 2)) 2)` because this would result in an infinite recursion. Although that could be handled by adding another base case:

```
(defun power (x n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 1)
        ((= n 2) (* x x))
        ((evenp n) (power (power x (/ n 2)) 2))
        (t (* x (power x (- n 1))))))
```

Comment: Well thanks, at least I know now that I didn't miss the point. Still it's a strange example. Especially as it is not really needed to do the optimization for even numbers at all, he'd better just omitted that.

Comment: The optimization is needed to get O(log n) performance, as mentioned in the documentation string: _This executes in log n time, because of the check for even n._